# Quadratic equation family with largest real root in Cyclotomic extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let the $\alpha_{k}$ be the largest real root by absolute value of $ 2x^2-2kx-(k-1)=0$ for all $k\ge1$.

For what values of $k$ does $\alpha_{k}$ sit in a cyclotomic extension? How does one explicitly provide the extension when an $\alpha_{k}$ does sit in a cyclotomic extension?

Comment: $\alpha$ is of degree 2, so the only way it can generate a cyclotomic field is if it is rational, or generates the field of 3rd or 4th roots of 1. That should narrow things down a lot.

Comment: Sorry what I intended to ask was different.

Comment: Surely you meant $x^2 - (2k-1)x - k = 0$, with $x^2 - (2k-1)x - kx = 0$, you get $\alpha = 3k-1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ ;)

Comment: Thankyou. I will modify the question.

Comment: You talk about $\alpha$ as if it were a single value. You also put the equations together as if they all have to be satisfied simultaneously. But your question suggests that both of these are false. Perhaps you're trying to define $\alpha_k$ to be the real root of $2x^2-2kx-(k-1)$ of largest absolute value for each $k\ge1$, and then asking for which $k$ does $\alpha_k$ sit inside a cyclotomic field?

Comment: It is known that every abelian extension of the rationals sits in a cyclotomic extension, and your extensions, being quadratic, are abelian. But for quadratics it's even easier, as one can use Gauss sums. For example, if $p$ is prime and 1 more than a multiple of 4, then $\sqrt p$ lies in the extension by $p$th roots of unity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So all the roots $\alpha_{k}$ for every $k$ sits in a cyclotomic extension? Is it possible to explicitly provide the extension?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oic. If $\alpha_{k} = \frac{k+\sqrt{k^{2}+2k-2}}{2}$ and if $k^{2}-2k+2 = \prod_{j=1}^{m}p_{j}^{i_{j}}$ where $p_{j}$ are primes and $i_{j}$ are multiplicity of primes that divide $k^{2}-2k+2$, then $\alpha_{k} \in \Bbb Q(\zeta_{p_{1}},\zeta_{p_{2}},\dots,\zeta_{p_{m}})/\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Not quite, e.g., $\sqrt7$ is not in the extension by 7th roots of unity, but $\sqrt{-7}$ is, so $\sqrt7$ is in the extension by 28th roots of unity. I've given you the keyphrase, "Gauss sums". Why not look that up and then come back to write a full answer to the question?

Comment: Could you give me a good reference? Wiki says Gauss proved a certain sum is $\sqrt{p}$ or $i \sqrt{p}$ depending on if  $p$ is $\pm 1 \pmod 4$.

(Just aside: can roots of higher power algebraic equations lie in cyclotomic extension?)

Comment: My second guess is then each $\alpha_{k} \in \Bbb Q(i,\zeta_{p_{1}^{i_{1}}},\zeta_{p_{2}^{i_{2}}},\dots,\zeta_{p_{m}^{i_{m}}})/ \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Of course roots of higher-degree polynomials can lie in cyclotomic extensions; $x^n-1$ for example. As Gerry mentions, the Kronecker-Weber theorem says that *any* abelian extension lies in a cyclotomic extension, in fact. I edited the question because the placement of the $\forall$ quantifier was deeply illogical and I didn't like looking at it.

Comment: How about non-abelian extensions?

Comment: It's impossible for a nonabelian extension to lie within an abelian one. (Why? Think about how their Galois groups are related.) Cyclotomic extensions are abelian extensions, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof quadratic number fields lie in cyclotomic fields via Gauss sums.

Suppose $L/K/{\Bbb Q}={\Bbb Q}(\zeta_n)/{\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{d})/{\Bbb Q}$ is a tower of Galois extensions, where $d\in{\Bbb Z}$ is squarefree.

Then $K$ is the fixed field $L^H$ for some $H\subset G={\rm Gal}(L/{\Bbb Q})$ by Galois correspondence.

What naive assumption could we make to force $G$ to be as simple as possible? The simplest possible groups to work with are cyclic groups. In particular, say $n=p$ is prime $>2$ for convenience.

Furthermore $[K:{\Bbb Q}]=2=[G:H]$ by Galois correspondence. As $G$ is even-order cyclic, its unique index-two subgroup is the set of squares $H=G^2$.

An artificial way to create an $H$-invariant element of $L$ is to sum over the $H$-orbit of an $\alpha\in L$, or equivalently to apply the trace map ${\rm tr}_{L/K}$. Might as well apply it to $\zeta_p$ of all things:

$$h:=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\zeta_p^{k^2}=2\sum_{u\in H}\zeta_p^u.$$

Technically we have summed over elements of the $H$-orbit of $\zeta_p$ *twice* since $k^2=(-k)^2$, but this rescaling shouldn't affect $H$-invariance. The luckiest we could get is if $g=\sqrt{d}$ already. It can be checked that this is not quite true, so there is still more work to do. Now here's a magic trick:

$$0=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\zeta_p^k=1+\sum_{u\in H}\zeta_p^u+\sum_{v\in G\setminus H}\zeta_p^v\iff h=-1+\sum_{u\in H}\zeta_p^u-\sum_{v\in G\setminus H}\zeta_p^h.$$

The $1$ is aesthetically annoying, so let's get rid of it by setting $g=h+1$. Then we can express $g$ as

$$g:=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)\zeta_p^k$$

where the Legendre symbol is defined to take the values $+1,-1$ depending on whether $k$ is a quadratic residue (i.e. square mod $p$) or not respectively. Observe that the Legendre symbol is a group homomorphism $G\to\{\pm1\}$ with kernel $H$. This $g$ is called a **Gauss sum**. They come in much more advanced forms elsewhere in number theory. For a good resource see [Hugh](http://www-math.mit.edu/~brubaker/houghexpsums05.pdf) (pdf).

Finally, let's check if we're lucky and squaring $g$ yields something useful. In order to do this though we need to be clever and think of $g$ as a special case of a "discrete Fourier transform." Define

$$g_a:=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{ak}=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{ak}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{ak}=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)g~~~(a\not\equiv0).$$

Now we compute an "inner product induced norm" in two different ways. First way:

$$\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}g_ag_{-a}=g_0^2+\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right)g^2=(p-1)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)g^2=(p-1)(-1)^{(p-1)/2}g^2.$$

This follows since $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a^2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$ is constant wrt $a$ and $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ by Legendre's formula $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\equiv a^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p$ and $g_0=0$. The second way of summing is

$$\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}g_ag_{-a}=\sum_{u=1}^{p-1}\sum_{v=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{u}{p}\right)\left(\frac{v}{p}\right)\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\zeta_p^{a(u-v)}=p\sum_{u=v=1}^n \left(\frac{uv}{p}\right)=(p-1)p$$

since the inner sum is $p$ if $u\ne v$ and $0$ otherwise. Equating results yields

$$(p-1)(-1)^{(p-1)/2}g^2=(p-1)p\iff g^2=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p.$$

Unfortunately this only tells us that ${\Bbb Q}(\zeta_p)\supset{\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p})\supset{\Bbb Q}$ for primes $p>2$. One can check though that $\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{2}\in{\Bbb Q}(\zeta_4)$, hence for any product $d=q_1\cdots q_m$ of distinct primes

$${\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{\pm d})\subseteq{\Bbb Q}(\zeta_4,\zeta_{q_{\large 1}},\cdots,\zeta_{q_{\large m}})\subseteq{\Bbb Q}(\zeta_{4d}).$$

Comment: What if $d$ has multiplicities of primes?

Comment: @Arul: Without loss of generality it doesn't. You can factor out squares from under the radical symbol, after all.